# Como apagar um commit no repositório remoto do GitHub?

Tags: git, github, commit, branch

Nunca havia passado por essa situação, tenho um repositório público no GitHub e preciso apagar os 5 últimos commits que eu fiz, tanto do local, quanto do remoto que aparece pra todos no GitHub. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Apagar um commit ou um branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que você se confundiu aí. Esse comando que você postou funciona, mas é pra deletar **branches**, não **commits**.

Se for pra deletar commits específicos, vc pode usar o rebase interativo: `git rebase -i HEAD~6` isso vai te deixar editar os 6 últimos commits, e aí é só trocar o `pick` por `d` ou `drop` na frente dos commits que vc deseja deletar, sair do rebase e dar um `git push -f`.

Comment: Leo, muito obrigado irmão, salvou muito! Só complementando caso alguém precise, para editar as linhas do rebase no VS use o "Insert" do teclado e deixe em Insert no VS, após editar, para sair, pressione ESC e então digite ":wq". (Pelo menos aqui funcionou assim)

Comment: @Gabriel eu não especifiquei como sair do rebase pq depende do editor que o cara tiver configurado no Git, mas é isso msm :)